# Programmatically create grid view

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I am working on an app in which i am trying to implement something like this :-

1: First of all,i created a button(whose name here is "Create a new folder"). On clicking that button,an alertview will appear which will ask for the name of the button which is going to be created on click.

2: The above process will be repeated each and everytime when we click on "create a new folder" button.

3:The buttons which are created at runtime will be arranged in a grid view format.

[image: Required arrangement will be like this.]

Above shown screenshot will let you know about the required arrangement.

I've tried this by using `UITableview` and making columns in it. But i am not able to create folders at runtime.Please help me find any way to solve this. Suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) if you can require iOS 6. There is a simple [Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012860) on Apple's site too.

Comment: Thank you so much  for making me aware of `UICollectionView`. It solved my problem.